# Visual Studio 2019. Не могу изменить путь запуска программы по Ctrl/F5

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Для работы мне удобно, чтобы сгенерированная программа находилось не в каталогах по умолчанию (Debug или Release), а во внешнем каталоге. EXE-шник там нормально создается, но при попытке запустить его по CTRL-F5 выдается ошибка, что он не найден, и ищется он по пути по умолчанию.
Попытки изменить пути в разных опциях проекта (которые я подозревал в данном действии) результата не дали, программа все время пытается запускаться из указанной директории. Похоже, что я не могу найти в настройках ту опцию, которую надо заменить на мой реальный путь. Может кто-то знает, в каком месте это надо сделать. Программа на C++. Заранее благодарен

Comment: Настройки проекта ->Debugging -> Command. Однако если "EXE-шник там нормально создается", то ничего менять не надо, так как путь по-умолчанию - это путь где создан exe.

Comment: Большое спасибо. После того, как я туда вставил явный путь все стало запускаться.

Comment: Но туда нет необходимости вставлять реальный путь

Comment: Возможно, но пока я это не сделал программа пыталась запускаться из папок Debug или Release в зависимости от конфигурации проекта.

Comment: По-умолчанию программа запускается из того места, где создан exe.

Comment: Я это уже понял и не спорю. Но, к сожалению, у меня происходит не так. Причину этого я не знаю. А то, что Visual ищет exe-шник не там, куда он сохранен, совершенно достоверно, так как в сообщении об ошибке указывается полный путь по которому он пытается найтись. И этот путь - директории по умолчанию.